# Identify non-domain remote clients with Item-Level targeting

Tags: group-policy, remote-desktop

I would like to apply a group policy preference setting (to deploy a shared printer) only if a user is connecting to a RDSH server from a non domain-joined client computer.  Many of these clients will come in through an RD Gateway Server.

Item-level targeting looks promising, particularly the Terminal Session item's **Client Name** parameter.  But the connecting clients are users' home computers over which I have no control of the names.  Further this parameter doesn't include the client's domain, so using "IS NOT *mydomain*"  isn't an option.

How can I apply my GPP setting only when the client computer from which the user is connecting to the RDSH server is not domain-joined?

Comment: I think you will need 802.1x/Network Access Protection for this.

Comment: I'm all ears! How would 802.1x/NAP help me distinguish non-domain clients for purposes of applying GP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your non-domain clients connect from an IP address that is *not in your domain network's IP address range*, then you can do the following to apply a Group Policy Preference Item to a user's session when he connects from a remote, non-domain workstation.

1. Link your Group Policy Object to a [WMI filter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc779036%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) that is only true when evaluated on the RDSH server (e.g. use a query like `SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem WHERE NAME='RDSERVER'`)
2. On the Group Policy [Preference Item](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn581922.aspx) to be applied to non-domain remote sessions, enable [Item Level Targeting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc733022.aspx), then:

   1. Add the **IP Address Range** item
   2. Specify **Is Not** in *Item Options*
   3. Provide the complete IP address range of the domain network

      **Note:** You can add the **IP Address Range** item multiple times to exclude several IP address ranges if the domain network uses multiple, non-contiguous IP subnetworks.